# How to generate Oracle sequence in order

Tags: oracle

As of now, we are using the sequence created with below SQL in Oracle DB to populate the request number value in our application.
It works fine but suddenly there is a gap in request number (i.e. sequence value returned). For e.g. previous value was 4061 and next value is 4082.
We think that it is happening due to small cache size and NOORDER.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "APPDATA"."APP_REQUEST_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 2281 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL;
```

Our customer is complaining that they are seeing lots of gaps in the request numbers.
So, we are planning to change our sequence as below with cache size set to 50000 and NOORDER changed to ORDER.
Can you please confirm if this will fix the issue with gap in sequence number.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "APPDATA"."APP_REQUEST_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 2281 CACHE 50000 ORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL;
```

P.S. We are expecting less than 50 requests per day in PROD and We are not using Oracle Real Application Cluster.

Answer (score 0):

When a sequence ages out of the cache, the cached values are lost.  When you see gaps of roughly 20 values, that is likely the cause.  Increasing the sequence's `cache`, therefore, will cause the gaps to be larger.  If you want to minimize gaps, you'd want `nocache`.

Setting a sequence to `nocache` will decrease the number and size of gaps.  It won't eliminate them.  It has a negative impact on performance but that may not be relevant for a table that sees only 50 inserts a day.  I'd be more concerned that the customers seem to care about sequence-generated values which often implies that a sequence was the wrong way to generate values in the first place.  If you're only creating 50 rows a day, it may make sense to produce a gap-free sequence of values in your query instead.

Comment: We are in UAT phase and till yesterday there was no such requirement. Customer came up with this requirement yesterday as gap is affecting their reporting somehow. There is a debate going on but I would like to be ready with solution if the requirement is accepted. Can you please explain what do you mean by 

'it may make sense to produce a gap-free sequence of values in your query instead.'

Comment: @Ranjeet - If something is "affecting their reporting somehow", my guess would be that you want those reports to have, say, `row_number() over (order by [date or key])` to produce the number rather than using the sequence-generated value.  That way they don't care about gaps in the sequence.

Comment: Here is something you may want to look into.  https://youtu.be/B5JltFoe5Ho